# View doesn't update on component property change in Angular 2 RC6 first time

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component in my project that calls a service to retrieve some (locally-stored) JSON, which is mapped to an array of objects and returned to the component to be displayed. The problem I am having is that the bindings in the view don't seem to update the first time I call the service, but do update the second time I call the service.

The component template:

```html
@Component({
    selector: 'list-component',
    template: `
        <button type="button" (click)="getListItems()">Get List</button>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Job Title
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr *ngFor="let employee of _employees">
                    <td>
                        {{employee.id}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{employee.name}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{employee.jobTitle}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    `,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
```

The component controller class:

```ts
export class ListComponent {

    _employees: Employee[];

    constructor(
        private employeeService: EmployeeService
    ) {

    }

    getListItems() {
        this.employeeService.loadEmployees().subscribe(res => {
            this._employees = res;
        });
    }
}
```

And the service:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {

    constructor(
        private http: Http
    ) { }

    loadEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]> {
        return this.http.get('employees.json')
         .map(res => <Employee[]>res.json().Employees);
    }
}
```

Things I've tried:

- Changing the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to `OnPush`
- Making the `_employees` property an observable, populating it with `this._employees = Observable<Employee[]>` and using the async pipe on the ngFor statement: `*ngFor="let employees of _employees | async"` - same situation, only populates on second button click

Can anyone spot anything wrong with my code, or are aware of any issues with RC6 that could lead to such behaviour?

Comment: Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` can you comment it and check?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - No, nothing.

Comment: @micronyks - The ChangeDetectionStrategy setting doesn't seem to have any bearing on the result whatsoever (even if removed)

Comment: I see many people have this problem, the same with me. Would be nice if some could post a proper solution.

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue. Still didn't get any solid solution. Using `detectChanges` works. Below is the workaround but please note that this is not the perfect solution

```
export class ListComponent {

_employees: Employee[];

constructor(
    private employeeService: EmployeeService,  private chRef: ChangeDetectorRef
) {

}

getListItems() {
    this.employeeService.loadEmployees().subscribe(res => {
        this._employees = res;
        this.chRef.detectChanges()
    });
}
```

}